# When does new InitialContext() throw a NamingException?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, initial-context

Can anyone explain in what case does new InitialContext() throw NamingException.

I read java docs and it us mentioned that this exception is thrown when a naming exception is encountered. But I don't understand why will a naming exception occur while initializing the context. I mean, I am not looking a name while initialing, so why will this exception occur when initializing it?

Answer (score 0):

Greping the [InitialContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/naming/InitialContext.java) will show you the answer.